# Add git branch name on bash command prompt in docker container

Tags: bash, git, docker

In my local bash, I could add git branch name on the bash command prompt
by adding below code in ~/.bashrc

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

I add the same code to docker container ~/.bashrc when making docker image.
However, it only colored the current directory but not showing branch name like below

```
user@server /workspace/mydir ()
```

what I expect was like below. The yellow bracket indicates which branch that I'm using.

```
user@server /workspace/mydir (master)
```

Comment: Is git installed in your container and how are you adding the git repo to your container? Are you mounting it?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch` in that directory?

Comment: @tentative yes I mounted host directory

Comment: @phd *master and test_branch

Comment: @phd nothing just 
()

Comment: @phd it works well outside the container. In the host directory which I mounted to the container, it returns (master)

Comment: side note : to get the active branch, you can use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Comment: from within the container : a. does `ls -d .git/` return something, or does it print an error ? b. does `git status` work, or does it return an error ?

Comment: @LeGEC a. It shows .git/ directory b. git status works well. It seems git works well. It is just not showing branch name.

Comment: `git branch --show-current` to avoid `sed`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I had to do in my Dockerfile where `<<USERNAME>>` should be replaced with the user that your docker is run as:

```
### Setup git branch view in CLI ############
RUN echo "parse_git_branch() {" >> /home/<<USERNAME>>/.bashrc \
    && echo "    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\\\1)/'" >> /home/<<USERNAME>>/.bashrc \
    && echo "}" >> /home/<<USERNAME>>/.bashrc \
    && echo "export PS1='\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ '" >> /home/<<USERNAME>>/.basic
```

The part that took me so long to figure this out is the three backslashes needed before the 1 in the grep of the sed command.

My troubleshooting consisted of my looking at my .bashrc file inside of my Docker instance. That is where I saw that the `(\1)` was being replaced with just `()`. So, if you're having this issue and my fix doesn't work for you, check your .bashrc file to see what it did do.